# Unexpected result when using slice assignment on outer dimension in nested python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

When using the following code in python 3.7.2 the assignment is silently ignored. Is that an expected outcome?

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> x[:][1]=17
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Is there a better way using slices to achieve the intended result of replacing the 2nd column with 17? Btw., I get the same result when using [17, 17, 17] to match the dimension.

Edit: Just to avoid some confusion. The intended result was [[1, 17, 3], [4, 17, 6], [7, 17, 9]].

Comment: To clarify, is your intended result `[[1, 2, 3], 17, [7, 8, 9]]`? If so, use `x[1] = 17`.

Comment: `x[:]` creates a shallow copy of the list, then you replace the *copy's* second element.

Comment: Numpy array would be another option you can consider

Comment: The key here is to understand that `list` objects *do not have rows and columns*. `list` objects are heterogeneous lists of Python objects. They have no notion of dimensionality, well rather, they all have *a single dimension* and the ordinality of that dimension is the list's *length*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x[:]` creates a copy of the original list and that new list modified in place.
However, this created list is inaccessible (since there is not reference to it).
If you want to get the second sublist as `[17,17,17]` i.e 
`x[0] = [17 for _ in x[0]]`

but if you want it to be just `[17]`, then
`x[0] = [17]`

Edit: Okay, looks like I misunderstood the question a bit, looks like you want to 
treat this as kind of matrix. For regular python list and nested lists there is no such syntactic sugar, you'd have to create a for loop:

```
for sublist in x:
    sublist[1] = 17
```

With list comprenhensions you would need to create a copy, which is not needed in the first place IMO. But if you want that

`copied_and_modified_x = [[sublist[0], 17, sublist[2]] for sublist in x]`

Comment: "and that new list modified in place" *and discarded*

Comment: it is not discarrded, i think it's still accessible via `_`, at least in the Python REPL, otherwise, yes, it's discarded

Comment: I don't believe that is what the OP wants, this is setting the first *row* to 17, the OP wants the second column

Comment: No, no it's not. The assignment statement doesn't evaluate to a value, so it isn't even saved in a REPL session.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the point that [:] makes a shallow copy. I guess I have to loop over the nested list.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for this?:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
y=[[l[0],17,l[2]] for l in x]
print(y)
```

Outcome is:

```
[[1, 17, 3], [4, 17, 6], [7, 17, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`id(x)` and `id(x[:])` are different, because `x[:]` creates a shallow copy of `x`. So, when you write

```
x[:][0][1] = 17
```

You're creating a new shallow copy of `x` and you're modifying the first sublist's first element by 17. But, the new result result has no reference, so can't access to it's content.

You could do this to get your desired result:

```
a = x[:] # creates a shallow copy of x
a[0][1] = 17
print(x, id(x))
print(a, id(a))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 17, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] 139933444652552
[[1, 17, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] 139933416357064
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use list slices if the result you want is

> x = [[1, 2, 3], [17, 17, 17], [7, 8, 9]]

You should just do:

> x[1] = [17,17,17]

When you use a slice it creates a new object that is equal to x, so it doesn't save on x variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
x, y = len(list1)-1, 0
while y <= x:
    print(list1[y][1], end=" ")
    y = y+1
```

Output:

```
2 5 8
```

**I Think This will Help You**